# Remove empty lists in pandas series

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a long series like the following:

```
series = pd.Series([[(1,2)],[(3,5)],[],[(3,5)]])

In [151]: series
Out[151]:
0    [(1, 2)]
1    [(3, 5)]
2          []
3    [(3, 5)]
dtype: object
```

I want to remove all entries with an empty list. For some reason, boolean indexing does not work.

The following tests both give the same error:

```
series == [[(1,2)]]
series == [(1,2)]

ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 4 vs 1
```

This is very strange, because in the simple example below, indexing works just like above:

```
In [146]: pd.Series([1,2,3]) == [3]
Out[146]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

P.S. ideally, I'd like to split the tuples in the series into a DataFrame of two columns also.

Comment: Why are you storing lists when storing tuples would suffice?

Comment: The series is the result of running `df.int_col.astype(object).combine(df.int_col2, func=it.find)` where `it` is an `IntervalTree` from the `bx-python` module. (I'm trying to get lookups in intervaltrees as a vectorized operation.)

Comment: And since that function is implemented in C I do not think I'll be able to change it any time soon.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could check to see if the lists are empty using `str.len()`:

```
series.str.len() == 0
```

and then use this boolean series to remove the rows containing empty lists.

If each of your entries is a list containing a two-tuple (or else empty), you could create a two-column DataFrame by using the `str` accessor twice (once to select the first element of the list, then to access the elements of the tuple):

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': series.str[0].str[0], 'b': series.str[0].str[1]})
```

Missing entries default to `NaN` with this method.

Comment: Thanks! Wonder why a series has a `str` and why calling `len` on this `str` returns False for empty lists.

Comment: I guess `str.len()`, although intended for use with strings, just called the object's underlying `__len__()` method. Often comes in handy for lists!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with with the latest pandas

Comment: @crypdick: just tried with pandas 1.1.3 on ubuntu and it seems to work correctly. Which version/platform are you using?

Comment: @Alex Riley pandas==1.0.3 on Ubuntu

Comment: @crypdick: I've just tried with 1.0.3, and cannot reproduce any errors (the OP's example df with the methods shown in this answer work correctly). What code are you using and what error do you get? Might be easiest to ask a new question directly on SO to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 6):

Using the built in apply you can filter by the length of the list:

```
series = pd.Series([[(1,2)],[(3,5)],[],[(3,5)]])
series = series[series.apply(len) > 0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `series` is in a bad state -- having a Series of lists of tuples of ints
buries the useful data, the ints, inside too many layers of containers.

However, to form the desired DataFrame, you could use

```
df = series.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]) if x else pd.Series()).dropna()
```

which yields

```
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  5
2  3  5
```

A better way would be to avoid building the malformed `series` altogether and 
form `df` directly from the data:

```
data = [[(1,2)],[(3,5)],[],[(3,5)]]
data = [pair for row in data for pair in row]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thanks. That series is the result of running a c function as a vectorized operation with `df.int_col.astype(object).combine(df.int_col2, func=it.find)`. Perhaps I could create a wrapper around `it.find(start, end)` that returns the tuple in the list this function returns.

Comment: If you are interested in speed you might want to time this code versus a plain Python list comprehension. Nothing being done here takes advantage of Pandas (label alignment) or NumPy (using object dtype gives up to any possibility of NumPy speed gain).

Comment: Thanks for that tip and all your other answers on SO! I'm guessing that it is the computations I want to do afterwards that are important to do in a DF. I thought Pandas vectorized operations would help me, but perhaps not.

Comment: Had to change `else pd.Series()` to `pd.NaT`