# delete rows with [ ] from a pd data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df in which a column named 'date' is like this

```
['2011-01-31',
 '2011-01-31',
 '2011-01-31',
 [],
 '2011-01-31',
 '2011-01-31',
 '2011-01-31',
 '2011-01-31',
 '2011-01-31',
 '2011-01-31']
```

I would like to delete the rows with 'date' == []. I tried the following code

```
df_new = df[df['date'] != '[]']
```

However, df_new is the same as df. Can anyone help me on this? I am using python 3 on windows 7. Thanks.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29100380/2285236)'s a similar question that suggests `df_new = df[df['date'].str.len() > 0]`

Comment: @ayhan thanks, it works.